# Calcular o total no boleto bancário

Tags: php, javascript

Talvez com a imagem dê para entender, eu tenho segundo a imagem, 2 produtos, na hora de gerar o boleto ele só pega o valor do primeiro produto, como fazer para resgatar o total corretamente?

[image: carrinho]

**O código PHP:**

```
$conn = conecta();
$total = 0;
$linha = Array();
foreach ($_SESSION['shop'] as $id => $qtd) {
    $cart = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE  id=$id");
    $cart->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cart->execute();

    while ($linha = $cart->fetch()) {
        $preco = $linha['preco'];
        $linha['preco'] = str_replace(",",".",$linha['preco']);
        $_SESSION['preco'] = $linha['preco'];
        $sub =  $linha['preco'] * $qtd;
        $total += $linha['preco'] * $qtd;
        // $total += $preco;
        // ------------------------- DADOS DINÂMICOS DO SEU CLIENTE PARA A GERAÇÃO DO BOLETO (FIXO OU VIA GET) -------------------- //
       // Os valores abaixo podem ser colocados manualmente ou ajustados p/ formulário c/ POST, GET ou de BD (MySql,Postgre,etc)    //

       // DADOS DO BOLETO PARA O SEU CLIENTE
       $dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento = 5;
       $taxa_boleto = 2.95;
       $data_venc = date("d/m/Y", time() + ($dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento * 86400));
       // Prazo de X dias OU informe data: "13/04/2006";
       $valor_cobrado = $sub;
      // Valor - REGRA: Sem pontos na milhar e tanto faz com "." ou "," ou com 1 ou 2 ou sem casa decimal
       $valor_cobrado = str_replace(",", ".",$valor_cobrado);
       $valor_boleto = number_format($valor_cobrado+$taxa_boleto, 2, ',', '');
       $dadosboleto["nosso_numero"] = '12345678';
       // Nosso numero - REGRA: Máximo de 8 caracteres!
       $dadosboleto["numero_documento"] = '0123';
       // Num do pedido ou nosso numero
       $dadosboleto["data_vencimento"] = $data_venc;
      // Data de Vencimento do Boleto - REGRA: Formato DD/MM/AAAA
      $dadosboleto["data_documento"] = date("d/m/Y");
      // Data de emissão do Boleto
      $dadosboleto["data_processamento"] = date('d/m/Y');
      // Data de processamento do boleto (opcional)
      $dadosboleto["valor_boleto"] = $valor_boleto;
     // Aqui eu quero inserir o valor total da compra.
   }
}
```

**E o JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('input').change(function (e) {
        id = $(this).attr('rel');
        $index = this.value;
        $preco = $('font#preco'+id)
                 .html().replace("R$ ",'');
                  console.log($preco);
        $val =   ($preco*$index).toFixed(2)
               .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');;
        $('font#sub'+id).html('R$ '+$val);
        clearInterval(timer);

     });
 });
```

Comment: Clayton seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow. É interessante dá uma lida no tour para entender melhor o funcionamento do site pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Tem como editar sua pergunta? está um pouco bagunçado.

Comment: Desculpem , eu gostaria de puxar o total geral e exibir na variavel  $valor_boleto,eu so consigo exibir o primeiro produto, nao soma com o proximo produto.

Comment: Amigo, edita sua pergunta colocando um pouco mais de informação, como por exemplo o erro que está retornando. Mas você já tentou retirar a linha `$total = number_format($total,2,".",".");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem 2 formas de fazer isso. Com o `php` e com o `sql`.

- **PHP**

  ```
      <?php

      $conn = conecta();
      $linha = Array();

      // criei um array chamado totalGarel que usaremos mais tarde
      $totalGeral = array();

      // apaguei o looping while pois ele não é necessário uma vez 
      //que você seleciona apena 1 id de cada produto por vez

      foreach ($_SESSION['shop'] as $id => $qtd) {
          $cart = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE  id=$id");
          $cart->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $cart->execute();

              $linha = $cart->fetch() 
             $preco = $linha['preco'];
             $preco = str_replace(",",".",$preco);
             $_SESSION['preco'] = $preco;
             $sub =  $preco * $qtd;
             $valor_cobrado = $sub;
            $valor_cobrado = str_replace(",", ".",$valor_cobrado);

          $totalGeral[] = $valor_cobrado;

      }


          // aqui vem a soma de todos os valores dos produtos selecionados
          $ValorTotalBoleto = array_sum($totalGeral);

          // REPARE QUE OS DADOS DO BOLETO ESTÃO FORA DO FOREACH
          // POIS OS DADOS SÃO ÚNICOS

           // DADOS DO BOLETO PARA O SEU CLIENTE
            $dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento = 5;
            $taxa_boleto = 2.95;
            $data_venc = date("d/m/Y", time() + ($dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento * 86400));
            // Prazo de X dias OU informe data: "13/04/2006";


            // aqui eu incluí o valor para ser somado com as taxas
          $valor_boleto = number_format($ValorTotalBoleto+$taxa_boleto, 2, ',', '');

          $dadosboleto["nosso_numero"] = '12345678';
            // Nosso numero - REGRA: Máximo de 8 caracteres!
            $dadosboleto["numero_documento"] = '0123';
            // Num do pedido ou nosso numero
            $dadosboleto["data_vencimento"] = $data_venc;
           // Data de Vencimento do Boleto - REGRA: Formato DD/MM/AAAA
           $dadosboleto["data_documento"] = date("d/m/Y");
           // Data de emissão do Boleto
           $dadosboleto["data_processamento"] = date('d/m/Y');
           // Data de processamento do boleto (opcional)
           $dadosboleto["valor_boleto"] = $valor_boleto;
          // Aqui eu quero inserir o valor total da compra.


      ?>
  ```

claro que pode haver algum erro, pois eu não fiz testes com o seu DB.

- **SQL**

Com o sql você pode montar uma `query` que faça essa soma direto do DB.

```
    $soma = $conn->prepare("SELECT  SUM (preco) FROM produtos");
```

Porém não consegui imaginar aonde poderia colocar e como montar essa `query` pois não conheço seu banco de dados. E pelo que eu percebi o seu carrinho é montado apenas por sessão o que dificulta ainda mais a montagem dessa `query`

De qualquer forma o php deve resolver.

Se tiver algum erro, poste ele no comentário que eu tento arruma-lo.

Comment: Vou testar aqui Andrei,obrigado!

Comment: Andrei Coelho muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente,valeu mesmo,se não for pedir muito teria como me ajudar com esse javascript,,qdo eu escolho cinco produtos no botao input ele aumenta o valor, mas na hora de enviar para outra pagina ou atualizar a pagina ele volta pro valor inicial,é o mesmo javascript acima.

Comment: Então @Clayton, seria bom você abrir uma nova pergunta relacionada isso, pois eu não sou profissional em javascript. Lembre de quando você postar essa pergunta, coloque o formulário do carrinho para que o profissional da área possa te ajudar. Provavelmente o problema está relacionado ao formulário de envio e/ou com o php, pois se o valor está atualizando significa que o javascipt está funcionando corretamente. Além disso, é importante postar perguntas de problemas  diferentes separadamente pois outra pessoa em um futuro pode usar para solucionar um outro problema. Fico feliz em te ajudar. Abs!